# Send live CMD output to function

Tags: function, powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a PowerShell script that runs CMD command and send the live stream back to PowerShell.

Each line that comes back from the stream, I am trying to send to a function; However, it is passed to the function only at the end of the cmd run instead of during it.

Important to mention that if I pass the stream to 'out-host' instead, I can see the results.

Can you assist?

```
    function get-ValidateProgress
    {
         param ([Parameter(Mandatory,HelpMessage='Value Passed from ValidateLDS.exe',Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]$ValidateLine)
         IF($ValidateLine -like 'Proccessing Active Users record*' )
         {
            $Current=$ValidateLine -replace 'Proccessing Active Users record ','' -replace 'of.*','' -replace ' ',''
            $TotalValue=$ValidateLine -replace "Proccessing Active Users record $Current of ",''
            [INT]$Progress=(($Current/$TotalValue)*100)
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity ValidateDBLDS -Status 'Proccessing LDS User records' -PercentComplete $Progress -CurrentOperation 'Active Users'
            IF($Current -eq $TotalValue){write-host 'Finished procccsing Active Users' -ForegroundColor Green}
         }
         ELSEIF($ValidateLine -like 'Proccessing Deleted Users record*' )
         {
            $Current=$ValidateLine -replace 'Proccessing Deleted Users record ','' -replace 'of.*','' -replace ' ',''
            $TotalValue=$ValidateLine -replace "Proccessing Deleted Users record $Current of ",''
            [INT]$Progress=(($Current/$TotalValue)*100)
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity ValidateDBLDS -Status 'Proccessing LDS User records' -PercentComplete $Progress -CurrentOperation 'Deleted Users'
            IF($Current -eq $TotalValue){write-host 'Finished procccsing Deleted Users' -ForegroundColor Green}
         }
    }



    Try{
    $cmdOutput = cmd.exe /c "cd /d D:\$Campus\Code\Utilities && ValidateDBLDS.exe /viewonly:false" 2>&1 | get-ValidateProgress

    Write-Host "Successfully finished LDS Validation." -ForegroundColor Green
    sleep -Seconds 2
    }
    Catch{
    Write-host "An Error occured during validating LDS. See full expection below.`nExecption:"$Error[0].Exception"`nTargetObject:"$Error[0].TargetObject"`nInvocationInfo:"$Error[0].InvocationInfo -ForegroundColor Red
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your function to receive *streaming* input via the pipeline - i.e., output objects (which in the case of external programs are *lines*) *as they're being emitted by the upstream command* - it **must use a `process` block**.

To use a simplified example:

```
function foo {
  # A process block is executed for each pipeline input object.
  # In the case of *external programs*, each *line* of output constitutes
  # an input object.
  process {
    "[$_]"
  }
}

cmd /c 'echo 1 & timeout 2 >NUL & echo 2 ' | foo
```

Executing this will echo `[1 ]` *before* the 2-second sleep `timeout.exe` call kicks in, proving that the `cmd /c` output was processed in a streaming fashion.

A function that lacks a `process` block is processed as if its body were enclosed in an `end` block, i.e. the block that is invoked *after all pipeline input has been received*.

See [Piping Objects to Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#piping-objects-to-functions).

Comment: Update:
Thank you, this really solved the issue.
The explanation in the comments (##) really helped to understand why it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @EliorMachlev; my pleasure.